# PHPExcel: Why is this not working? The data is not populating

Tags: mysql, phpexcel

Looking for a little help with this. I am using PHPExcel to populate an excel spreadsheet with data from a MySQL table. I have already created the column headings, added the properties, etc and that all shows up fine on the spreadsheet. My connection the database is good, but no data is being placed into Excel. I've gone over the code many times, but have not found the culprit as of yet. I'm wanting to start the data insert on row 8 of the spreadsheet and wanting the rows to increment. I have included the PHPExcel.php file, setActiveSheetINdex(0). Am I not setting the cell values properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the PHPExcel code I'm using.

```
$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM clients");

    $row = 8;

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_object($query))
    {

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet() 
            ->setCellValue('A'.$row, $data->client_name) 
            ->setCellValue('B'.$row, $data->r_date)
            ->setCellValue('C'.$row, $data->w_reconst)
            ->setCellValue('D'.$row, $data->size_code)
            ->setCellValue('E'.$row, $data->b_techAmount)
            ->setCellValue('F'.$row, $data->i_techAmount)
            ->setCellValue('G'.$row, $data->j_techAmount)
            ->setCellValue('H'.$row, $data->s_techAmount)
            ->setCellValue('I'.$row, $data->m_techAmount)
            ->setCellValue('J'.$row, $data->c_techAmount)
            ->setCellValue('K'.$row, $data->k_techAmount);
    $row++;
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked if you query is actually returning any rows?

Comment: How are you saving the file?

Comment: I dug a bit deeper and discovered I didn't have the path correct when I included the config.php  file at the top. It's now populating the data. Thanks Bartez, your response put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write your data on file

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM clients");

$row = 8;

while($data = mysqli_fetch_object($query))
{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet() 
        ->setCellValue('A'.$row, $data->client_name) 
        ->setCellValue('B'.$row, $data->r_date)
        ->setCellValue('C'.$row, $data->w_reconst)
        ->setCellValue('D'.$row, $data->size_code)
        ->setCellValue('E'.$row, $data->b_techAmount)
        ->setCellValue('F'.$row, $data->i_techAmount)
        ->setCellValue('G'.$row, $data->j_techAmount)
        ->setCellValue('H'.$row, $data->s_techAmount)
        ->setCellValue('I'.$row, $data->m_techAmount)
        ->setCellValue('J'.$row, $data->c_techAmount)
        ->setCellValue('K'.$row, $data->k_techAmount);
    $row++;
}

//$filename = 'file name - ' . time() . '.xlsx';
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');
```